# BGRT Errors on boot - Custom compiled kernel 3.19.3

Tags: boot, kernel

After compiling my own kernel (yes, I know I'm not entitled to any support), I receive this message on boot:

```
[    0.077204] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
```

It disappears after a few seconds and continues to boot with no problems. I looked up the driver and it appears to be an Intel technology (I'm using an AMD CPU), so that could be the cause.

**Ubuntu 14.10 - Kernel version 3.19.3**

Thanks in advance,
 - Monty.

Comment: Same problem as yours in Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon. Browsing on the internet one can find that a lot of distros have similar problems and it seems one has to wait for some new kernel updates.

Comment: Okay - that sounds like the only solution.